# how can I count by week, month, and YTD with postgres?

Tags: postgresql

under Postgres 9.3 I am trying to run a query to summarize some data from table a:

```
| Entry date-Date | Customer ID-charvar | received-Boolean | Processed-Boolean | finalized-Boolean | billed-Date |
```

I would like use `count(case when)` to count all the records by the current week, month, then all of time into table b:

```
|report date | Total Received Weekly | Received Monthly | Received all of time | so on...
```

I am having a difficult time wrapping my head around how to write that query.  I have thought about extracting the week day and month number to determine my records to sum for each length of time but then how would I make it repeatable without having to change the dates so I could automate it to run weekly through either PgAgent or CRON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too long for a comment now: I don't speak PGSQL so try adapting the following for your date extraction functions:

```
SELECT
     MAX(CurrentWeekCount) As CurrentWeekCount
    ,MAX(CurrentMonthCount) As CurrentMonthCount
    ,MAX(AllCount) As AllCount
FROM
(
```

> count all the records by the current week

```
    SELECT
     COUNT(CustomerID) As CurrentWeekCount
    ,NULL As CurrentMonthCount
    ,NULL As AllCount
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE DATEPART(week, YourDateColumn) = DATEPART(week, GETDATE())

    UNION ALL
```

> month

```
SELECT
     NULL As CurrentWeekCount
    ,COUNT(CustomerID) As CurrentMonthCount
    ,NULL As AllCount
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE DATEPART(month, YourDateColumn) = DATEPART(month, GETDATE())

    UNION ALL
```

> all of time

```
    SELECT
     NULL As CurrentWeekCount
    ,NULL As CurrentMonthCount
    ,COUNT(CustomerID) As AllCount
    FROM YourTable
) x
```